# Transform periodogram to dataframe in R

Tags: r, foreach, period

Simple example with R on mydata:

```
l=structure(list(dat = structure(1:9, .Label = c("01.01.2016", 
"02.01.2016", "03.01.2016", "04.01.2016", "05.01.2016", "06.01.2016", 
"07.01.2016", "08.01.2016", "09.01.2016"), class = "factor"), 
    lpt = c(94L, 3L, 30L, 92L, 20L, 80L, 20L, 190L, 52L)), .Names = c("dat", 
"lpt"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))


l=ts(l)
spectrum(l)
```

R returned plot with periodogram

[image]

On this periodogram we can see  bursts of values (two bursts 0.23, 0.45).

How should the values of the x-axis and the у-axis be reduced to a dataframe, but only for those values on the x axis that are bursts?

Second question: 
Can these values be displayed not in frequencies, but in absolute, original units(dat,lpt)?

Comment: `df <- data.frame(freq = spectrum(l)$freq, spec = spectrum(l)$spec[,2])` gives a dataframe with the x- and y-values of the plot. How would you define a burst?

Comment: @brettljausn,bursts are extremely high points on the curve.